# Why is the statement using relation operators evaluate to 1 in the following code?

Tags: c, logical-operators

Shouldn't the value of i be 0?
Since x

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
         int x = 10,y=20,z=5,i;
         i=x<y<z;
         printf("%d",i);
         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: what did you expect?

Comment: x<y is true but y<z s false so shouldn't i be false and be equal to 1?

Comment: @MusarratAhmed: Which part of your code do you think represents the logic that you expressed as "but" in English?

Comment: @KerrekSB Well said sir. :) I've added a link to my answer for the associativity. Any chance you're having a better one sir?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I think you covered it just fine :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, due to the [LTR associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of the relational operators,

```
 i=x<y<z;
```

evaluates to

```
i=(x<y)<z;
```

which is

```
i=(10<20)<z;
```

which is

```
i= 1 < 5;
```

which is TRUE (1). That `1` gets stored in `i`. That's it.